# Error with executable file using hosted WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

I'm new to WCF services, I'm trying to replicate tutorial of "Hosting a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service

I managed to create service and its installer (in ServiceProject), I managed to install service with sysutil command. I was able to connect to service from separate console project (let's name it TestProject) and call its functions - it works when I run them from Visual Studio. The problem is: when I'm trying to use executable file of TestProject - it doesn't work. I tried to do it after manually starting service from windows services list, but it just returns error. Can you help me with understanding what I'm doing wrong?

The code I'm trying to run from TestProject looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                WinWCFServiceClient client = new WinWCFServiceClient();
                client.ShowTextMessageAsync("it works as win service!!!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There were errors");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The end");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

It crushes with exeption looking like this:

> ? System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
> ? System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
> ? System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
> ? System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
> ? System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) ? System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
> ? System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory() ? System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait) ? System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
> ? System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
> ? WinWCFServiceClient..ctor() ? C:\Projects\Training Projects\WCF Service\CheckWinWCF_NF\generatedProxy.cs:?????? 35
> ? CheckWinWCF_NF.Program.Main(String[] args) ? C:\Projects\Training Projects\WCF Service\CheckWinWCF_NF\Program.cs:?????? 16

And my service looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IWinWCFService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void ShowTextMessage(string str);
    }

 public class WinWCFService : IWinWCFService
    {
        public void ShowTextMessage(string str)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You send this message {0}:", str));
        }
    }
```

Installer part:

```
public class WinWCFServiceBase:ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        public WinWCFServiceBase()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "WCFWinServiceRS";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new WinWCFServiceBase());
        }

        // Start the Windows service.
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and
            // provide the base address.
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WinWCFService));

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start
            // listening for messages.
            serviceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // 
            // WinWCFServiceBase
            // 
            this.ServiceName = "WinWCFServiceRS";

        }
}
```

Comment: A service by default runs with a System Account that has no environmental variables like PATH.  So it is be3tter to create a service account on machine and start service with the Service Account instead of the default System account.

Comment: The error information you provided doesn't seem complete, I checked the documentation and you get an `EndpointNotFoundException`?

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service#install-and-run-the-service) mentions: If you make changes to the service, you must first stop it and uninstall it. To stop the service, right-click the service in the SCM and select "Stop", or `type net stop WCFWindowsServiceSample` at the command prompt .

Comment: Note that if you stop the Windows service and then run a client, an EndpointNotFoundException exception occurs when a client attempts to access the service. To uninstall the Windows service type `installutil /u bin\service.exe` at the command prompt.

Comment: Yes, I understood part about unregistering and registering service again - did it like it's advised - it didn't help. Also I managed to find source codes of this tutorial at link bellow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms751414(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I tried to run them (registered service, then tried to use executable of client) - and they return same mistake. So either there are some additional operations which I need to do with service for it to work, or it's like jdweng wrote about service account, but I can't test it now.

Comment: I suggest you to check where the error message mentions.`C:\Projects\Training Projects\WCF Service\CheckWinWCF_NF\generatedProxy.cs:?????? 35 ? CheckWinWCF_NF.Program.Main(String[] args) ? C:\Projects\Training Projects\WCF Service\CheckWinWCF_NF\Program.cs:?????? 16`.